# How convert [x] into x?

Tags: list, python-2.7, scipy, output

I would like to know how convert my output [54] to 54, here my code :

```
list_p=[]
list_aire=[0,0,1,2,3,1,1,1,0,0]


puissance=[list_aire[1:8]]
simpsaire=(scipy.integrate.simps(puissance,dx=6))
simpsaire=simpsaire.tolist()
simpsaire = map(int, simpsaire)
#u=";"
#str(u.join(simpsaire))
list_p.append(simpsaire)

#j = list_p.astype(np.int)
```

The solution is probably obvious, you can see the other solution that i try before (with # in code), but i can't find the solution, so how , when i did:

```
print simpsaire
```

to get :

```
54 and not [54]
```

with the method of simpson ?

Ty for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: simpsaire = simpsaire[0] doesnt help?

Comment: Erf, i didn't see simpsaire as a list for all the time, i try to convert it and i was wrong, ty for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you adding the brackets?  Compare these calculations:

```
In [442]: from scipy import integrate

In [443]: integrate.simps([0,0,1,2,3,1,1,1,0,0],dx=6)
Out[443]: 54.0
```

The extra brackets turn the input into a 2d array, so the integration is now an array - one element per row of the input:

```
In [446]: x=integrate.simps([[0,0,1,2,3,1,1,1,0,0][1:8]],dx=6)

In [447]: x
Out[447]: array([ 54.])
```

Look at what your expressions produce

```
In [448]: x.tolist()
Out[448]: [54.0]

In [449]: list(map(int,x.tolist()))
Out[449]: [54]
```

there are simpler ways of doing this

```
In [450]: int(x)
Out[450]: 54

In [451]: x[0]
Out[451]: 54.0

In [452]: x.item()
Out[452]: 54.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I understand my mistakes now, ty !